# Django get value from foreign key in views.py

Tags: django

I am a beginner in dango. I am trying to retrieve the price from the service and make a sum of all the prices. I am asking for help.

## logopedija/models.py

```
class Pricelist(models.Model):
name=models.CharField('Name of service', max_length=60)
price=models.DecimalField(default=0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)

def __str__(self):
return "%s %s" % (self.name, self.price)

class Service(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, limit_choices_to={'active': True},)
service=models.ForeignKey(Pricelist, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
day=models.DateField(default=date)
time_service = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TIME-CHOICE, default="16:00")
is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
return f"{self.user.name} | dan:{self.day} | time:{self.time_service} | service:{self.service.price}"
```

## logopedija/views.py

```
def show_service(request, service_id):
service = Service.objects.get(pk=service_id)
return render(request, 'users/show_service.html', {'service':service})
```

## logopedija/show_service.html

```
{% extends 'pacijenti/base.html' %}

    {% block content %}

\<div class="card"\>
\<div class="card-header"\>
Detalji termina
\</div\>
\<div class="card-body"\>
\<h5 class="card-title"\>{{ service }}\</h5\>  
\<p class="card-text"\>
{{ service.id }}\<br/\>
{{ service.user }}\<br/\>
{{ service.service }`your text`}\<br/\>
{{ service.day }}\<br/\>
{{ service.time_service }}\<br/\>
\</p\>
\</div\>
\</div\>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What do you want to sum up? Because with your current model setup your `Service` is only allowed to be connected to one single `Pricelist`. And your `Pricelist` has only one price. Maybe you can describe the relationship of your models with words?

Comment: One html page is a price list and the other is an appointment(service). when making an appointment (service), I choose an option from the price list together with the price. The idea is to add up the total number of appointments (services) per month and create a monthly sum of payments on a separate html page. Thank you for your help!